# How can I skip a specific validation when importing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I skip a specific model validation when importing data?

For example, suppose I have this model:

```
class Account
  validates :street_address, presence: true
end
```

Normally, I don't want accounts to be saved without addresses, but I'm also going to convert a lot of data from an old system, and many accounts there don't have addresses.

My goal is that I can add the old accounts to the new database, but in the future, when these accounts are edited, a street address will have to be added.

### Clarification

As I said, I want to skip a **specific** validation; others should still run. For example, an account without an account number shouldn't be loaded into the new system at all.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
class Account
  attr_accessor :importing
  validates :street_address, presence: true, 
    unless: Proc.new { |account| account.importing }
end

old_system_accounts.each do |account|
  # In the conversion script...
  new_account = Account.new
  new_account.importing = true   # So it knows to ignore that validation
  # ... load data from old system
  new_account.save!
end
```

Comment: Having a boolean in the database is a good approach.  You might consider editing the title, as this is really about before and after states of data, not so much about conditional validation.

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr - actually, in my example, the boolean doesn't get persisted; it's just an `attr_accessor`. That way it goes into the database, but once there, it's not treated specially, and will require a street address from anyone updating it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to do the conversion one time (i.e, after importing the old data you won't need to do this again), you could just [skip validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations) when you save the imported records instead of modifying your app to support it.

```
new_account.save validate: false
```

Comment: Except that I want to skip only **specific** validations, not all of them.

Comment: I see. Then I think your way is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

note that

```
account.update_attribute(:street_address, new_address)
```

will skip validations as well.  #update_attributes (notice the 's') run validations, where update_attribute (singular) does not.

Comment: `update_attribute` triggers a save immediately. I'd rather set all my attributes and save once.